# Mongodb querying find subdodument and query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a Job Schema and a application schema. Application schema has been embedded in job schema. This is like candidates who have applied on this particular job

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a745a49e4a4d9203cf506ed"),
        "active" : true,
        "applications" : [ 
            {
                "applied" : true,
                "shortlisted" : true,
                "interviewed" : false,
                "offered" : false,
                "hired" : false,
                "rejected" : false,
                "candId":1
            }, 
            {
                "applied" : true,
                "shortlisted" : false,
                "interviewed" : false,
                "offered" : false,
                "hired" : false,
                "rejected" : false,
                "candId":2
            }, 
            {
                "applied" : true,
                "shortlisted" : false,
                "interviewed" : false,
                "offered" : false,
                "hired" : false,
                "rejected" : false,
                "candId":3
            }, 
            {
                "applied" : true,
                "shortlisted" : false,
                "interviewed" : false,
                "offered" : false,
                "hired" : false,
                "rejected" : false,
                "candId":4
            }
        ],
        "job_title" : "MERN Stack developer",
        "job_description" : "<p>If more than one component needs to make use of this, we have to either duplicate the function, or extract it into a shared helper and import it in multiple places - both are less than ideal.</p><p>Vuex allows us to define \"getters\" in the store. You can think of them as computed properties for stores. Like computed properties, a getter's result is cached based on its dependencies, and will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed.</p><p>Getters will receive the state as their 1st argument:</p>",
        "max_experience" : 3,
        "max_salary" : 4,
        "min_experience" : 2,
        "min_salary" : 3
    }
```

In my application i have stages that a candidate goes through like (applied, shortlisted, interviewed, offered ...)

So i want to write a query which will give me a result in applied stage

```
           {
                "applied" : true,
                "shortlisted" : false,
                "interviewed" : false,
                "offered" : false,
                "hired" : false,
                "rejected" : false,
                "candId":2
            }, 
            {
                "applied" : true,
                "shortlisted" : false,
                "interviewed" : false,
                "offered" : false,
                "hired" : false,
                "rejected" : false,
                "candId":3
            }, 
            {
                "applied" : true,
                "shortlisted" : false,
                "interviewed" : false,
                "offered" : false,
                "hired" : false,
                "rejected" : false,
                "candId":4

            }
```

basically only applied should be set to true and others to false

and in shortlist stage

```
           {
                "applied" : true,
                "shortlisted" : true,
                "interviewed" : false,
                "offered" : false,
                "hired" : false,
                "rejected" : false,
                "candId":1
            }
```

query result with job or without job doesn't matter

**Edit**

```
Job.find({
    _id : req.params.id,
    'applications.applied': req.body.applied,
    'applications.shortlisted' : req.body.shortlisted,
    'applications.interviewed' : req.body.interviewed,
    'applications.offered' : req.body.offered,
    'applications.hired' : req.body.hired,
    'applications.rejected' : req.body.rejected
  }).populate('applications.talentId').then((job, err) => {
    if(err){
      return res.status(500).send({error: "There was some error"})
    }
    res.status(200).json(job)
  })
```

i am getting entire job object with all the applications in every stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following aggregation

```
db.jobs.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id : ObjectId("5a745a49e4a4d9203cf506ed") } },
    { $unwind: "$applications" },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$applications"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            applied: true
        }
    }
])
```

Basically to filter nested collection you can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) first to have separate documents for each element of `applications` array. Then you can reshape them using [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to end up having only single applications and then you can use $match to filter them just as if they were single documents. You can add more conditions to $match according to your business requirements.

EDIT:

- $uwind takes nested array of `n` documents and returns `n` documents with one element of that nested array in each.
- $replaceRoot simply reshapes each of your documents so that nested subdocument becomes a new root (used here to get rid of unnecessary properties)

Comment: hi @mickl , i am new to mongodb , can u please tell me what this unwind, replaceRoot do

Comment: Sure, edited my answer, also please check out links to mongodb docs to see the examples

Comment: @hi mickl , i could not solve this problem, i have to first find the job by id, then $unwind by applications and then replaceRoot and then finally match applied, shrortlist .... right?

Comment: @waq true, that should be what you need

Comment: it worked, i was facing problem objectId, i am using mongoose schema and i have never specified ObjectId as mongoose does it by default but when using aggregate i had to specify, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For `applied`:  check if `applied` is true and `shortlisted` is false.

For `shortlisted`: check if `shortlisted` is true and `interviewed` is false.

and so on..

You check whether that stage is `true` and next stage is `false`.

For example, for people in `applied` stage the query would be:

```
Job.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5a745a49e4a4d9203cf506ed"),
          applications: {$elemMatch: {applied: true, shortlisted: false}}}, 
         {applications: 1})
```

For looking at the applied stage candidates, you have to use aggregate:

```
Job.aggregate([{$match: {_id: ObjectId("5a745a49e4a4d9203cf506ed") /* first match the job Id */ }},
               {$unwind: '$applications' /* expand the array */}, 
               {$match: {'applications.applied': true, 'applications.shortlisted': false}}])
```

Comment: can u have a look at my question i had tried this way but that didnt work

Comment: I added an example query. Try that.

Comment: this query is for which stage applied or shortlist?

Comment: that is for `applied`. The first query I wrote, will help you update the documents, of course you have to use `update` instead of `find`. The second `aggregate` query is just for reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Job.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$applications",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true // optional
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $match: {
                'applications.applied': true,
                'applications.shortlisted': false,
                'applications.interviewed': false,
                'applications.offered': false,
                'applications.hired': false,
                'applications.hired': false,
                'applications.rejected': false
            }
        },

    ]



);
```